# How do you change the MoTD for a Minecraft Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

All I want to do is post my Minecraft server on the main Minecraft Servers website but I don't really know what to do with the code they gave me. Please help?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "main Minecraft Servers website." You've been mislead or are simply misinterpreting the site.

Answer (score 12):

The Message of the Day (motd) can be changed in the server.properties file. The line you're looking for should be at the bottom: `motd=A Minecraft Server`. Just change that to whatever you want your message to be, though there seems to be a limit of 59 characters according to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties). You can also change the formatting using some standard [formatting codes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes).

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Minecraft server folder then open the server.properties file. If you scroll down  at the bottom you should see something saying `motd=(your motd)`. Replace that with the code they gave you and run the server.

Answer (score 1):

Near the bottom of `server.properties`, you will see `motd=A Minecraft Server`

Change `A Minecraft Server` to whatever you want.