# Minecraft Forum, MoTD how do you change it!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I made a server on Minecraft Forum (because it was easier) and it said:

> To finish claiming this server, set this token *token removed* somewhere in your server's MoTD. Once the server is verified, you can remove the token.

How do I change the MoTD?**MOTD**

**Minecraft Forum Does Make Servers Not Only Listing**

Comment: Anyone? I need help

Comment: You asked 3 minutes ago, give it some time. Anyway Minecraft Forums does not offer server hosting. It is simply a list of existing servers, and to verify that you are the owner of the server you're adding it wants you to change the MOTD, see [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150029/how-do-you-change-the-motd-for-a-minecraft-server) for details.

Comment: But how do you change it!?

Comment: See the answer I linked ( http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150029/how-do-you-change-the-motd-for-a-minecraft-server ) for details.